# Redirect existing second page to non-existing url

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-redirect

I have a site https://sitename.com/web (example). So, full path to page is sitename.com/web/index.php. On ftp server there is folder /web which also contain second page file - index-2.php. How to avoid creating /web-2/ folder and redirect index-2.php to sitename.com/web-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, create an `.htaccess` file inside the root folder of your site, then add the following lines to it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^web-2$ index-2.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

This site might help you with htaccess:

https://www.htaccessredirect.net/

A nice tutorial on .htaccess files also below:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file

Comment: Doesn't work. I want my link https://sitename.com/web/index-2.php (existing file and path) to be shown as https://sitename.com/web-2/ (non existing path)

Comment: have you tried creating an `.htaccess` file in the root of your domain and adding that?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file well maybe it's missing something... take a look at this tutorial about htaccess, im sure you'll find your answer there... htaccess is the key to achieve what you want.